# why mail function is no longer working after i sent more than 100 emails?

Tags: php

This is the code i´m runing:

```
<?
                            

ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );



$from = "Daniel Panno <danielderecife@gemail.com>";
$to = "danielderecife@gmail.com";
$subject = "Pedido de Carteles";
$message = "texto de prueba";
$headers = "De:daniel@objetivos.net";
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Cabeceras adicionales
$cabeceras .= 'To: Daniel <danielderecife@gmail.com>, danmusic <danmusic@yahoo.com>' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'From: '.$from. "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: daniel@objetivos.net' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: dpanno@rafa2000.com.ar' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message, $cabeceras);
echo "El email fue enviado.";



?>
```

originally, the code received some POST variables, and I thought thos were not being passed correctly,so i wrote the above code to test and it still wont work

Comment: Maybe some limitation from gmail?

Comment: i tried to send to yahoo, to my domain and its the same